# When does the XSLT document() function run schema validation on the external XML file?

Tags: .net, xml, validation, xslt, xsd

Suppose I'm calling `XslCompiledTransform.Transform` on a reader created with `ValidationType.Schema`, `XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessSchemaLocation` and with a resolver capable of finding the actual XSD files referenced from a schemaLocation attribute.  Suppose that the transform contains a `document()` function call which reads a secondary input file which came into existence between the compilation of the transform and the `Transform` call and which contains a useful schemaLocation attribute - unlike the primary input to the transform which didn't have any schemaLocation attribute (and for which no XSD is even defined anywhere).  Plot twist: the secondary input is not valid against the XSD which it references.

The same facts made into a story:

- Two files are provided.
- One file is fed as the input to the transform.
- It has no associated schema and no `schemaLocation`.
- The second file is accessed through the `document()` function from the transform.
- It has a `schemaLocation` which references an available XSD.
- The XSD itself is valid.
- The second file is not valid against the XSD.

Question is, will the `XslCompiledTransform.Transform` call try to validate the secondary input?  More precisely, will it throw an `XslTransformException` with an inner `XmlSchemaValidationException` demonstrating a validation error in the secondary input, when that secondary input is well-formed but invalid?

Well, the above is embedded in a huge, complicated unit test.  And that exact same unit test performs validation (and throws) when executed from Visual Studio Test Explorer, and it transforms successfully (and returns) when executed from a Resharper Unit Test Session (running within that same Visual Studio instance).

Now I wonder which of the two behaviors is "more correct"?  I can't find any documentation or spec that would care to comment on this scenario.

Comment: If by "correct" you mean "conformant with W3C specifications", I'm afraid the W3C specs don't give you an answer. The .NET System.Xml.Xsl processor is an XSLT 1.0 processor, and all XSLT 1.0 tells you is that the resource identified by the URI is "parsed as an XML document"; it doesn't tell you whether that includes DTD or Schema validation; the conclusion has to be that this is implementation-defined.

Comment: @MichaelKay - Thank you Michael, I feared as much.  Even Microsoft's documentation is short of clues.  At least they publish their source code.  I will keep digging.

Comment: Gave up on this.  Enabling EnableLegacyXmlSettings under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\XML looked promising (with tests run in the x86 architecture), but it didn't have any effect either.